# iOS 5: renderInContext erase context

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, render, ios5

My app is fully working on ios4.
I incrementely drawing over the context. I m using renderInContext before drawing on the layer to keep the previous drawing. In iOS 5, the new draw which is called with drawInRect erase the context with the full rect. For example if i have a full colored square in the context and i m drawing a line on it with drawrect, i have à transparent square around the line in the square...
Do you know how to avoid this and having only the Line over the square...?? Like it is in ios4!
Thank you

Comment: After some investigation... I saw that in ios4 the retain count  of the view is 1 before drawrect, 2 into, 1 after. And all rect to redraw are send correctly. In iOS 5, the count is 2,3,2.. And at the first calls, the rect is the self.bounds and not the correct rect!! ... Do you havé an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way of drawing. Using an image and drawing into it